# IIS - adding a website : HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized access

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have added a website on my IIS manager and assigned the port 90 to it in the Binding section. When I try to access it on a browser, I get the following error

```
HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control    list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.
```

I have added a new user `IIS_IUSRS` to the web.config file, the folder containing the files as well as the the site on the IIS manager and given it all permissions.

However, this error does not go away.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give access to **network service** account on your app folder